# Почему не вызывается обработчик Complete?

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Есть код реализующий плавное появление кнопки:

```
DoubleAnimation A = new DoubleAnimation();
A.From = 0;
A.To = 0.99;
A.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
btn4.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.OpacityProperty, A);
A.Completed += A_Completed;
```

Обработчик события A_Completed в этом случае не вызывается.

Пока писал вопрос в практическом плане проблему решил - нужно поменять две последние строки местами :

```
A.Completed += A_Completed;
btn4.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.OpacityProperty, A);
```

Однако все равно не ясно почему так происходит (я конечно догадываюсь что в BeginAnimation что-то происходит)?

Comment: Рискну предположить что там вызывается Freeze и анимация становится неизменяемой.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, тоже так предполагал, но нет, `A.IsFrozen = false` и не меняется...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключевая фраза содержится в [Общих сведениях о временных событиях](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/timing-events-overview#registering-for-clock-events-with-a-timeline) в Microsoft Docs:

> When you register for the Completed event on a timeline, for example,
>   you're actually telling the system to register for the Completed event
>   of each clock that is created for the timeline. In code, you must
>   register for this event before the Clock is created for this timeline;
>   otherwise, you won't receive notification. This happens automatically
>   in XAML; the parser automatically registers for the event before the
>   Clock is created.

DoubleAnimation – это наследник класса Timeline, который содержит только лишь описание еще не стартовавшей анимации. Когда вы вызываете метод BeginAnimation, под капотом создается объект типа Clock, который отвечает за работу отдельной анимации, и продолжает свою работу асинхронно, уже не имея никакой связи с первоначальным Timeline. Поэтому на событие Completed нужно подписываться заранее.